# Find UI-elements from SlidingTabLayout tabs

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project which requires ListViews in SlidingTabLayout tabs to be filled with data, yet, when I start the program, the lists do not appear. I've already debugged to make sure the data is actually sent there, which happens perfectly.

The xml for the activity itself:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<com.example.jafeth.wearnote.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The xml for the tabs:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swiperefresh1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jafeth.wearnote.ZabbixActivity">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/errorTextView" />
```

The code for the activity:

```
package com.example.jafeth.wearnote;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * An activity that shows all the possibilities for communication with  Zabbix.
 * Created by Jafeth on
 */
public class ZabbixActivity extends ListActivity {

private ViewPager pager;
private ViewPagerAdapter madapter;
private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
private CharSequence Titles[]={"Triggers","Events"};
private int Numboftabs =2;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout1, swipeRefreshLayout2;
private ListView listView1, listView2;
private StableArrayAdapter stableArrayAdapter1, stableArrayAdapter2;
private ArrayList<ZabbixModel> models1, models2;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zabbix);
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    madapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);
    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(madapter);

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_1, pager);
    View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_2, pager);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    listView1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView2 = (ListView) view2.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    models1 = new ArrayList<ZabbixModel>();
    models2 = new ArrayList<ZabbixModel>();
    stableArrayAdapter1 = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, models1);
    stableArrayAdapter2 = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, models2);
    //Defines the global variables of the object.
    token = LoginActivity.getToken();

    swipeRefreshLayout1 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh1);
    swipeRefreshLayout2 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh2);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View


    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    swipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshListener(this));
    swipeRefreshLayout2.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshListener(this));

    listView1.setAdapter(stableArrayAdapter1);
    listView2.setAdapter(stableArrayAdapter2);

    fillList();

}

@Override
protected void clearList() {
    models1.clear();
    models2.clear();
    stableArrayAdapter1.fillMap(models1);
    stableArrayAdapter2.fillMap(models2);
    stableArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    stableArrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void addModelsToList1(ArrayList<ZabbixTriggerModel> z) {
    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
        models1.add(z.get(i));
    }
    stableArrayAdapter1.fillMap(models1);
    stableArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void addModelsToList2(ArrayList<ZabbixEventModel> z) {
    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
        models2.add(z.get(i));
    }
    stableArrayAdapter2.fillMap(models2);
    stableArrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Fills the list of subactivities.
 */
@Override
protected void fillList()
{

    //Makes it so that the SwipeRefreshLayout can show that the list is refreshing, even if the refresh is started without a swipe.
    if(!swipeRefreshLayout1.isRefreshing())
    {
        swipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    if(!swipeRefreshLayout2.isRefreshing())
    {
        swipeRefreshLayout2.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    //Empties the ListView so that it doesn't show the same thing(s) twice.
    clearList();

    //Creates the JSOn Obejct that is sent to the server.
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("usertoken", token);

    //Sends the request.
    Ion.with(this)
            .load("https://zwm-tvdgeer-sping.c9.io/zabbix/triggers.php")
            .setJsonObjectBody(json)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        boolean b = true;
                        int i = 0;
                        ArrayList<ZabbixTriggerModel> models = new ArrayList<ZabbixTriggerModel>();
                        while (b) {
                            //Fills the ListView and notifies the user.
                            if (result.get(String.valueOf(i)) != null) {
                                ZabbixTriggerModel model = new ZabbixTriggerModel();
                                model.setTriggerid(result.get(String.valueOf(i)).getAsJsonObject().get("eventid").getAsString());
                                model.setDescription(result.get(String.valueOf(i)).getAsJsonObject().get("value").getAsString());
                                models.add(model);
                            } else {
                                b = false;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        addModelsToList1(models);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.refreshComplete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (e != null) {
                        //An error happened while collecting data, but the connection itself is functional.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.mainError + ": " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        //Something is wrong with the server connection.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.connectionError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });



    //Sends the request.
    Ion.with(this)
            .load("https://zwm-tvdgeer-sping.c9.io/zabbix/events.php")
            .setJsonObjectBody(json)
            .as(new TypeToken<JsonObject>() {})
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        boolean b = true;
                        int i = 0;
                        ArrayList<ZabbixEventModel> models = new ArrayList<ZabbixEventModel>();

                        while (b) {
                            //Fills the ListView and notifies the user.
                            if (result.get(String.valueOf(i)) != null) {
                                ZabbixEventModel model = new ZabbixEventModel();
                                model.setEventId(result.get(String.valueOf(i)).getAsJsonObject().get("eventid").getAsString());
                                model.setValue(result.get(String.valueOf(i)).getAsJsonObject().get("value").getAsString());
                                model.setClock(result.get(String.valueOf(i)).getAsJsonObject().get("clock").getAsString());
                                models.add(model);
                            } else {
                                b = false;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        addModelsToList2(models);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.refreshComplete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (e != null) {
                        //An error happened while collecting data, but the connection itself is functional.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.mainError + ": " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        //Something is wrong with the server connection.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.connectionError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    swipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
    swipeRefreshLayout2.setRefreshing(false);
}

/**
 * Adds one or more Strings to the list of subactivities
 * @param s An array of the Strings to be added.
 */
private void addStringsToList(ArrayList<String> s)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < s.size();i++) {
        strings.add(s.get(i));
    }
    stringAdapter.fillMap(strings);
    stringAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_zabbix, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Can anyone help me find a way to make the ListViews show up again?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. As it is now it is not clear what your question actually is, perhaps you could sum up what you need to know at the end.

Comment: Is it better like this? Other information I can add?

Comment: That does help and make it clear you have a question to ask. The only other possible improvement you could make to improve chances of getting an answer would be to explain anything you have tried so far and what happened. Good luck getting a quick answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.